# Can't open designer view for classes in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I tried to open up one of my older projects (from about 8 months ago) and I can't open up the designer view for any of my windows. I think this probably has something to do with the fact that I used Jetbrains Rider instead of visual studio back then. Right now my solution explorer looks like this:
[image: solution explorer]

Is there any way to fix this or do I just have to recreate the whole project in VS and paste all of the code over

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nevermind, I feel kind of stupid. I opened the solution as a folder instead of as a project. Opening as a project fixed my problem

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.